# Passing a php variable as a delimiter to php explode()

Tags: php, html, explode, delimiter

I am trying to pass a php variable as a delimiter to explode(). The variable's value is being fetched from an html form.

form:

```
<select name="delimiter">
<option value="\t">Tab Space</option>
<option value=",">Comma (,)</option>
<option value=";">Semi colon (;)</option>
<option value="&">Ampersand (&)</option>
<option value="|">Pipe (|)</option>
</select>
```

php:

```
$delimiter=$_POST['delimiter'];
$arr=explode($delimiter, $line);
```

Above doesn't seem to work. It does not recognize the delimiter and hence gives me a single element in $arr i.e. same as $line.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: have you tried echoing the $delimiter before it goes to explode?

Comment: If you `var_dump` the `$delimiter`, do you get the expected value as a string?

Comment: Yes, I have. If I select tab from the form it gives me "\t" but it doesn't work in the explode function. If I manually initialize, $delimiter="\t", and then pass it to explode it works just fine.

Comment: Yes sir, I do. Just a single string with the expected value.

Comment: `\t` has no meaning in html. Your $_POST value will literally be a backslash and a "t", **NOT** a tab character. `$var = "\t"` in PHP, however, **WILL** be interpreted as a tab character, because that's what `\t` is in double-quoted strings.

Comment: I know of the fact. I am using the character in php and fetching literally '\t' from html. I have demonstrated that in the question.

Comment: No, that is not what you are fetching. \t is provided as a way for you to represent a tab in your source code. For all other strings, escape sequences will not work and hence what you will get is the string "\t" rather than a tab character.

Comment: Can you provide a solution to the problem? using $delimiter="\t"; and $arr = explode($delimiter, $line); works just fine, but not $delimiter=$_POST['delimiter']; which gives me "\t" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don`t you use preg_split for this.. for example

```
<select name="delimiter">
<option value="\t">Tab Space</option>
<option value=",">Comma (,)</option>
<option value=";">Semi colon (;)</option>
<option value="&">Ampersand (&)</option>
<option value="\|">Pipe (|)</option>
</select>
```

and php script

```
$delimiter =  $_POST['delimiter'];

$arr =  preg_split("/".$delimiter."/", $line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to be the way that your `$line` is setup.
This works for me:

```
$string = "hello\tworld\tthis\tis\tfun";

$options = ["\t"=>'tab', ','=>'comma', ';'=>'semi-colon', '&'=>'amperstand','|'=>'pipe'];

echo "<form method=\"post\">";
echo "<select name=\"delimList\">\r\n";
foreach($options as $val => $option){
    echo "<option value=\"$val\">$option</option>\r\n";
}
echo "</select>\r\n";
echo "<input type=submit></form>";
if(isset($_POST['delimList'])){
    $delim = $_POST['delimList'];
    $array = explode($delim, $string);
    print_r($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest I got to a solution is the following line in php:

```
$delimiter =  $_POST['delimiter'];

eval("\$delimiter = \"$delimiter\";");
```

Initially, `$delimiter` is created `string(2)` after `eval` becomes `string(1) tab` in php.